# Cinematic blocked in AC Brotherhood

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

I am in the temple of Junon (after the Colosseum), and Ezio takes the apple, and draws his hidden blade, and then it is blocked. Nothing happens for a long time, it isn't frozen. Is it normal? How to solve that?

[image: screenshot]

EDIT:

The camera and the light effects moves slowly, but Ezio doesn't move. The music still pays

PS: I already tried restarting the games and I'm on w7 x64

Comment: Define "it is blocked [...] it isn't frozen". Does your game look just like the Youtube screenshot, or do the fancy light effects still move, but everything else (such as Ezio) don't? If so, I'd say it's a multithreading bug; most likely a deadlock or something.

Comment: @Nolonar please see edit

Comment: Hmm, I never encountered this problem myself, so I can't answer for certain, but let's see if [setting the game's processor affinity](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/change-the-processor-affinity-setting-in-windows-7-to-gain-a-performance-edge/5322/) to use only 1 core might fix this. You'll need to set it before the game hangs and once you're past that point you may set it back; I suppose AC would run very slowly on only one core, but at least the chances of a deadlock happening will be much lower.

Answer (score 1):

After watching a video, it turned out that I need to hit a key. Any key (<kbd>Q</kbd> worked for me) to continue the video

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @kotekzot Well, actually, it does provide an answer to the question. The cinematic wasn't really frozen, it waited for a key input. Vinz243 could have written what key he pressed ...

Comment: If you pay attention to the screenshot, you'll see youtube's minibar play progress. So all you have to do is press the space bar (lol jk).

Comment: @Fabián in fact I was a bit lazy so I njust took a screenshot of a video corresponding to the moment rather than running the game once mor.

Comment: It's ok man, I could have done the same. lol